# Is my proof that $\log(1+x) = 1 - \frac 1 2 x^2 + \frac 1 3 x^3 - \dotsc$ is not an algebraic power series sound?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, power-series, complex-geometry

I want to show that the power series
$$g(x) = \log(1+x) = x - \frac 1 2 x^2 + \frac 1 3 x^3 - \frac 1 4 x^4 + \dotsc$$
is not algebraic. By definition, $g$ is algebraic if there exists a non-zero polynomial $P \in \mathbb C[x,y]$ with
$$P(x, g(x)) = 0. \tag{1} \label{eqn1}$$
I know that this can be done using a theorem by Eisenstein¹, but I came up with a different proof:

Suppose $g$ is algebraic, with polynomial $P$ as in \eqref{eqn1}. Wlog we may assume that $P$ is irreducible. Then the inverse function $f(x) = e^x - 1$ is also algebraic, because
$$\tag{2} \label{eqn}P(f(y),y) = P(f(y), g(f(y))) = 0.$$
In particular, the graph $\Gamma = \{(f(y), y) : y \in \mathbb C\}$ of $f$ is contained in the algebraic curve
$$C = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb C^2 : P(x,y) = 0\} \supset \Gamma.$$
However, the graph $\Gamma$ contains all the points $(0, 2\pi i \cdot k)$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$. This can only happen if $C = \{x = 0\}$ and $P = x$, which is a contradiction to \eqref{eqn}.

Is that proof sound, or did I miss something?

---

¹ See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_theorem) or Pólya and Szegö's *Problems and Theorems in Analysis II*: If a rational power series $$a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \dotsc$$ represents an algebraic function, then there is a number $T \in \mathbb N$ such that $$a_1 + a_1 Tz + a_2 T^2 z^2 + \dotsc$$ has integer coefficients. In particular, the denominators of the $a_i \in \mathbb Q$ can only have finitely many prime factors.

Comment: Hmm...looks fine to me

Comment: Does that "Proof" hold when $f(x)=1-x^3$ & $g(y)=(1-y)^{1/3}$ ? If YES :: It is wrong ! If NO :: Where will it break ?

Comment: @Prem The answer is "no". Your functions $f$ and $g$ obtain each value only finitely many times, because their graphs are contained in the curve $C = \{y = 1 - x^3\}$. The function $e^y - 1$ obtains the value $0$ infinitely many times, at all the points $y = 2\pi i k$.

Comment: What did Eisenstein really say?  Presmably he did not think $$(1-x)^{1/2} = 1 - \frac{1}{2}x +\frac{1}{8}x^2-\frac{1}{16}x^3+\dots$$is transcendental?

Comment: @GEdgar you are right, I gave a more precise statement of Eisenstein's theorem.

Comment: Oh ok. My Earlier Comment was the Objection which @GEdgar raised , but I did not expand the cube root to show the unbounded Denominators !