# If $A\to B$ is an integral ring morphism, so is $A[[x]]\to B[[x]]$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

(Notation $R[[x]]$ means the ring of formal power series over $R$, a commutative ring with unity.)

Observations:

1. Since $A\to B$ integral implies $A[x]\to B[x]$ integral, $B[x]\subset B[[x]]$ is integral over $A[[x]]$. Thus it would suffice to show that the integral closure of $A[[x]]$ in $B[[x]]$ is closed in the $(x)$-adic topology.
2. Since we have a commutative diagram
   $$
   \require{AMScd}
   \begin{CD}
   A[x]@>>> B[x]\\
   @VVV@VVV\\
   A[[x]]@>>> B[[x]]
   \end{CD}
   $$
   it would suffice to show that $B[x]\to B[[x]]$ is integral, for $A[x]\to B[[x]]$ would be integral too and then we may apply [[02JM](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02JM)]. However, I don't have hope this is true (update: red_trumpet explained why this is false in a comment).
3. If $A\to B$ is finite, then $A[[x]]\to B[[x]]$ is finite too (and in particular integral). Thus, a counterexample must come from a non-finite integral morphism $A\to B$ (equivalently, integral but not of finite type). Indeed, if $A\to B$ is finite, then so is $A[x]\to B[x]$. Thus there is a surjection $A[x]^{\oplus n}\to B[x]$ of $A[x]$-modules. If $(x)\subset A[x]$, then $(x)$-adic completion of $A[x]$-modules gives a surjection $A[[x]]^{\oplus n}\to B[[x]]$  of $A[[x]]$-modules [[0315](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0315)], i.e., $A[[x]]\to B[[x]]$ is finite (analogously, one in general proves that finite modules are stable under adic completions).

I suspect not every element of $B[[x]]$ will be integral over $A[[x]]$. Consider $A=K$ a field and $B=\overline{K}$ an algebraic closure. Suppose $\overline{K}/K$ is not finite (for instance, this happens if $K$ is a finite field). Then, for non-zero $a\in K$, my guess is that the formal power series $\sum_{i\geq 1} a^{1/i}x^i\in\overline{K}[[x]]$ won't be integral over $K[[x]]$. However, I am unable to prove it. I tried by induction on the degree of the integral relation equation and it doesn't work.

Comment: The extension $B[x] \hookrightarrow B[[x]]$ is not integral in general. For example the power series $$f(x) = \log(1+x) \subset \mathbb C[[x]]$$ does not satisfy any polynomial equation $$p(x,f(x)) = 0,$$ for $p \in \mathbb C[x,y]$. In particular it cannot be integral over $\mathbb C[x]$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716764/is-my-proof-that-log1x-1-frac-1-2-x2-frac-1-3-x3-dotsc-is-not) for a reason.